# Read Parquet File Error Spark on Azure Synapse Workspace

Tags: exception, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I am running a pyspark job using azure synpase workspace. My Spark Job is failing with following error.  Can someone help me in debugging this error?

This error is coming in spark application run by Pipeline on Azure Synapse

```
Stacktrace: An error occurred while calling o1394.execute.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 94.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 94.0 (TID 2313) (vm-1d164027 executor 3): java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(BytesUtils.java:85)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:520)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:505)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:499)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:476)
    at
```

Comment: Can you share the command how you are reading parquet file. If you are using absolute path then replace "/some random.parquet"  with "/*.parquet ". As while converting table to parquet file , it is possible that data broke because of partition error." Also do not pass name of parquet file while creating as it can corrupt the large file."

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the Spark job is failing because it is encountering an EOFException while reading Parquet files. This suggests that there is something wrong with the Parquet files themselves, and that they are either incomplete or corrupt.

To debug this issue, you will need to inspect the Parquet files themselves to see if there is anything wrong with them. One way to do this is to use the "parquet-tools" command-line tool. This can be used to examine the contents of Parquet files, and can be helpful in identifying issues such as missing or corrupted data.

If you are unable to identify the cause of the issue using the parquet-tools tool, it's possible it could be a library implementation issue.

Comment: Hi  JDong, My job was working fine until a new version of wheel file (Created by another team) is added into the spark pools. Could it be new version that caused the issue. It is getting difficult to pin point the exact place which caused the issue.